# Create folder on iCloud from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I am developing an iPhone app were I want to create a folder from my application on iCloud.

Is it possible to create folder on iCloud programmatically at all?

I want to add image files, text files and audio files in that folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can create folders. When you call [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:] you get back a file URL for your container and you can put any file hierarchy in there you please.

Sounds like you're just getting started so I suggest you start with Apple's [iCloud for Developers Documentation and Videos](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/). Specifically you will want the Advanced iCloud Document Storage video as you'll want more control than CoreData and UIDocument will provide. Apple refers to this this type of iCloud storage as a "Shoebox App".